# Haskell Lenses: Difference of two HashSets in Folds

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-optics

Given:

```
f1, f2 :: Fold Box (HashSet Thing)
```

how do I write a fold that focuses the Things that are in f1 but not in f2? It would (of course) be the same Box, but f1 and f2 filter its contents differently.

I can see that `filtered` and `hasn't` might come into it and `HashSet.difference` would do the gruntwork, but I can't quite figure out the plumbing.

Comment: Or should it be a Traversal?

Comment: How would you write a `filter` for lists with folding?

Comment: I'm not sure how that comes into it. I was hoping some lens magic would do it very concisely.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly question. f1 is just a field of Box but f2 is a filter of f1's contents, and the answer would be the converse filter. It's not meaningful to speak of stuffing the answer back into Box, so I don't really want an optic.